# Merging 2 lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have the following list of dictionaies:

```
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 298}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumCashBack': 10586}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': 14}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumTotal': 40}
```

how would i merge these so that the cardscheme key is unique - this will involve merging the sumRefund and sumCashback into the same line ( example shwon below), but i can't figure it out.

```
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': 14}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumTotal': 40, 'sumRefund': 298, 'sumCashBack': 10586}
```

Comment: Is your desired output correct? Like in the case of `MasterCard`, there is no `sumRefund` and `sumCashBack `, but you have it in your desired output...

Comment: oh sorry, i completely messed that up, i'll edit it to fix, thankk for letting me know

Comment: defaultdict soln posted time: 8.650000000010039e-05 whereas the two loops posted (by me :) ) below that 2.3500000000176158e-05. That is significant, however it remains to be seen if list contains thousands of entries the margin narrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dictionary [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method together with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Assuming that `L` is the original list:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

cardschemes_rules = defaultdict(dict)

for dic in L:
    cardschemes_rules[dic['cardscheme'] + dic['posid']].update(dic)
    
cardschemes_rules.values()
```

*As you requested in the comment, each output correspond to the union of keys for a given `(cardscheme, posid)` pair.*

Running this code with the following `L`:

```py
L = [
    {'posid': 'A', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 2.98},
    {'posid': 'A', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumCashBack': 105.86},
    {'posid': 'A', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': .14},
    {'posid': 'A', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumTotal': .40},
    {'posid': 'B', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 298},
    {'posid': 'B', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumCashBack': 10586},
    {'posid': 'B', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10},
]
```

Would produce `cardschemes_rules.values()`:

```
{'posid': 'A', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 2.98, 'sumCashBack': 105.86, 'sumTotal': 0.4}
{'posid': 'A', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': 0.14}
{'posid': 'B', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 298, 'sumCashBack': 10586}
{'posid': 'B', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10}
```

If you have name collisions in your input, the last entry in the input list will remain (value are replaced by a new one every time `update` is applied).

Comment: This works great for when there is a single `posid` how would i allow for multiple `posid` keys to be present?

Comment: If there are several `posid` you will need to include `posid` in the `cardschemes_rules` key, for example `cardschemes_rules[dic['cardscheme']+dic['posid']`, this way you will have updating dictionaries for each `cardscheme`, `posid` pair. Any key including both fields would do. It just needs to be unique for every pair of `cardscheme`, `posid`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [  
    {'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 298},
    {'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumCashBack': 10586},
    {'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': 14},
    {'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10},
    {'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumTotal': 40}
]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for line in data:
    df = df.append(line, ignore_index=True)
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.groupby('cardscheme').sum()

df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Hope I helped :-)

Comment: This is very close, but when it runs I lose the posid value

Comment: u can use a list of args to group by eg.  df.groupby(['cardscheme', 'posid']).sum()

Answer (score 0):

Tried with minimum iterations but this is the best I cameup with.

Code:

```
lst = [{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 298},
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumCashBack': 10586},
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': 14},
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10},
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumTotal': 40}]

uniq_lst = []
for dct in lst:
    updated = False
    for dct_res in uniq_lst:
        if dct_res['posid'] == dct['posid'] and dct_res['cardscheme'] == dct['cardscheme']:
            dct_res[list(dct.keys())[2]] = list(dct.values())[2]
            updated = True
            break
    else:
        uniq_lst.append(dct)
        updated = True
    if not updated:
        uniq_lst.append(dct)

for ele in uniq_lst: 
    print(ele)
```

Output:

```
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa Debit', 'sumRefund': 298, 'sumCashBack': 10586, 'sumTotal': 40}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'MasterCard', 'sumTotal': 14}
{'posid': 'AZDEMOBirminghamB134', 'cardscheme': 'Visa', 'sumTotal': 10}
```